# Symfony Paginator, error @Enum

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination, doctrine

I'm trying to add a pagination on a query with Doctrine and the Doctrine class Paginator :

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('a.id'))
            ->from('MyProjectBundle:Account', 'a')
            ->leftjoin('a.first', 'fd')
            ->leftjoin('a.second', 'fr')
            ->where('a != ?1')
            ->setParameters(array(1 => $account))
            ->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $per_page)
            ->setMaxResults($per_page);
```

And like in the documentation for Paginator, i do :

```
return new Paginator($qb);
```

I have this error :

```
{

    "code": 500,
    "message": "[Semantical Error] The annotation \"@Enum\" in property Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\GeneratedValue::$strategy was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a \"use\" statement for this annotation?"

}
```

I include `use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;` and i don't know why i have this error ?

Comment: Same problem here. What are you importing beside Paginator ? ( I don't use Paginator so it doesn't come from that )

Comment: what is the version of doctrine2?

Answer (score 4):

Are you at some point after returning the paginator instance attempting to serialize it with something like JMSSerializer? If so, the serializer doesn't know how to serialize a paginator instance and will give you a (very unhelpful) error such as yours. Instead you have to give it a copy of the results in a format it can use, e.g.:

```
$serializableResults = $paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy();
$serializer->serialize($serializableResults);
```